# I get this ValueError when i try to run my code

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

i am trying to run the following code but getting this error don't know why.
ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; expecting 2613

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('train_set.csv',encoding='latin-1')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
con = sqlite3.connect("TrainSet.db")
df1.to_sql("Table1",con)
con.close()

text = []
for i in df1['SentimentText']:
    text.append(i)
for i in range(len(text)):
    text[i] = word_tokenize(text[i].lower())

stpwrds = stopwords.words('english')
stpwrds.extend(['.',',','-','_','&','!','@','*',')','(',':','/',';'])
stpwrds = set(stpwrds)

for i in range(len(text)):
    text[i] = list(set(text[i]) - stpwrds)

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
for i in range(len(text)):
    for j in range(len(text[i])):
        text[i][j] = lemmatizer.lemmatize(text[i][j], pos='v')

for i in range(len(text)):
    text[i] = ' '.join(text[i])

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
X = matrix[:7000]
Y = np.array(df1['Sentiment'][:7000])

f='such horrible movie, never gonna watching it again!!!'
f=word_tokenize(f.lower())
for k in range(len(stw)):
    while stw[k] in f:
        f.remove(stw[k])

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
for i in f:
    i = lemmatizer.lemmatize(i,pos='v')

f= ' '.join(f)

g=vect.fit_transform([f])
g=g.toarray()

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X.toarray(),Y)  <--- 
                                                                 MemoryError 
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = lr.predict(g)   <---ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; 
                             expecting 2613
```

Can someone help me to get this error solved? Also i'm getting memory error while executing train_test_split.

Comment: Please provide your input data format and mark which line the error is pointing to!

Comment: input format is a numpy.ndarray which is my variable 'g' here. Error is pointing to this line ----> lr.predict(g)

Comment: `numpy.ndarray` is an input *type*, but we'd need the input *format* to be able to help. Your question as is is under-defined.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've edited my code. Please have a look.

Comment: Okay but you still didn't include what's in 'train_set.csv'... Tell us what your data looks like! What's the format? How many columns, rows, what kind of data etc. etc....

Comment: There are 3 columns(itemID,sentiment,sentimenText) and 99989 rows in train_set.csv. itemID contains serial number for each sentiment, Sentiment contains label for each of the sentiment(0 or 1) and SentimentText conatins  twitter comments.